# Car rolls back when braking at low speed on 14 ' Audi S4 (B8.5)

Tags: audi, braking, bushing

I have just been changing my brake pads for the first time and my mechanic has noticed something unusual. He told me that whenever he brakes at low speed, the car rolls back a bit. According to him, the problem is most likely in the arm bushing (if I heard him right).

I have observed the car from outside and indeed, I did notice that the wheel jerks a bit backwards before stopping.

The car has gone though 42,000 km and I have not got into large potholes or went over curbs. I drive my car reasonably with thought of keeping it as long as possible.

So, is this a known issue, or is this an issue at all and should I be worried?

P.S. I had my 40k service just few weeks ago and they haven't spotted anything at that time.

Comment: That's just odd and trippy but I"m a motorcycle guy so......

Comment: Have a reputable mechanic check the suspension for any worn out parts and solve any issue found. You do not want to take it easy with worn out suspension components.

Comment: By "jerks a bit backwards", do you mean it rotates backwards, or it moves backwards in the wheel well?

Comment: Wheels seem rotating backwards a bit. Looks very strange from the outside.

Comment: Any chance of a video of this behavior? It sounds very strange.

Comment: What? How is that possible if car is moving forward, wheels can't move backwards without making noise and halting the car. They got to stop first.

Comment: It looks like the wheel slips.

Comment: @racefever worn-out suspension would be *extremely unlikely* on a S4 with just something over 40.000 km. My last A6 made 320,000 km with factory-installed shocks, springs and control arms, before I had them replaced after a spring failure.

Comment: @eYe a control arm bushing failure should be sufficiently easy to detect for a mechanic with a test bench (or even just an autohoist). I don't know about regulations in your place, but where I live, there is a mandatory inspection every 2 years where such problems get noticed and have to be resolved if you want to keep driving your car. I would consider it rather unlikely, though. Especially since control arms do not have any effect on the rotation of the wheel, just camber/alignment and direction it is facing. Just consult a VW/Audi mechanic, this simply might be working as designed.

Comment: @the-wabbit Audi's are kinda known for having issues with the control arms. Either way, this is something to take seriously (not saying that you are not already).

Answer (score 2):

If it's the control arm bushings, you should notice that the wheel itself shifts a bit backward in the wheel well. It certainly is bad for other components as well as vehicle handling because you get instantly outwards toe angle on your wheel.

If it is the bushing, get it replaced.